# Delegate or closure for multiple event in same object

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, delegates, closures

There is

```
var tableView: MyTableView?
tableView?.onGoToA = {
    self.goToA()
}
tableView?.onGoToB = {
    self.goToB()
}
tableView?.onGoToC = {
    self.goToC()
}
```

are there better way for this case or better that just use delegate?

Comment: please add more context and what are trying to do

Comment: I think OP is wondering if a delegate or closure should be used when an object can send multiple events

Comment: Off topic , dont use `;` in swift code

Comment: What about using the same closure but returning a parameter. `tableView.onGo = { [weak self] item in guard let strongSelf = self else {return} strongSelf.goTo(item) }` and `func goTo(_ item: "whatever the item type is") { // Do the go logic here }`

Comment: the thing is both are the same it's just a way to implement it, you should take care of self-tough, aware of retaining cycle if your using closure and delegates in cellforRowAt  !!!

Comment: You can check apple iOS frameworks code, they say for long running and async task callback you should use blocks. To handle any action on a view you should use Delegates.

Answer (score 3):

If you have limited possible cases, I would have single closure that takes a enum as an argument and will have a switch case to decide which method to trigger

If each event has a value associated with it you can exploit enums with associated values as well :)

Example:

```
enum EventType {
    case toA
    case toB
    case toC
}
```

Declare your closure as

```
var routerBlock: ((EventType) -> ())? = nil
```

Finally have router block implemented as

```
tableView?.routerBlock = {[weak self] (eventType) in
            switch eventType {
            case .toA:
                self?.gotoA()
            case .toB:
                self?.goToB()
            case .toC:
                self?.goToC()
            }
        }
```

You can use the similar approach with delegates as well. Rather than having 3 delegate methods you can have one method which takes `EventType` and have the same switch block to decide which method to trigger

Hope this helps

Comment: @luhuiya : welcome :) Please consider accepting answer if u think its useful, happy coding